# Microsoftonline.com, is this legit?

Tags: windows-8

A couple weeks back I went to google and type in Office 365 to login and download the suite from my account after restoring my PC.

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=office%20365

The top link I clicked very aimlessly as I did not assume for it to be anything else other than Microsoft on top was this link here.

https://login.microsoftonline.com

I entered my details and notices it failed to log in so went back found the other link and logged in successfully.

Here's the deal though, YES I have 2-step verification so my phone is needed to log in to websites from new devices, however I've noticed strange happenings on my newly reset PC.

The first one being errors in programs not being able to read files in %AppData% although they are right there.

Secondly my action centre pops up randomly asking me to enable Window Defender which it is and when I click the notification it simple opens my System32 folder.

Thirdly, my Adobe Creative Cloud application will sign out without command every 5 minutes, I log back in, continue working and then the icon goes grey again and signs back out.

Fourth, Applications like Photoshop and Illustrator which can get preview boosts using my GPU keeps flagging up none detected and I need more than 512mb or vRAM to do such actions which I do actually have as I'm playing games smoothly on high graphics with high fps.

Finally, when going to my system info page it says:
Processor: Not Available
RAM: Not Available.

Yet my Task Manager shows they are working perfectly.

Is it possible my PC is infected with some annoying piece of software screwing with the data around my computer? Drivers and such? 
Also how legit is the website mentioned in the title because I have Windows 8.1 and I load up my PC using the account I entered blindly into this website.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly the domain name is correct. That is the generic login page for all Microsoft Online services. You might not always see it depending on how you normally log in.

The nature of the login service means that it takes a noticeable time after you enter your ID before you can enter your passcode. Sometimes this can be several seconds. What is happening is that the login service checks your ID against its master list and works out whether it is a Microsoft account (such as business partner or live.com/outlook.com) or an enterprise tenant account. When it works it out, it may actually change the look of the login page (for example, we have a customised login page for Office 365).

As to the problems with your PC. Hard to say. Certainly you should run a couple of malware checkers to see if they find any issues though I have to say, those kinds of problems are more normally associated with hardware issues, particularly drive errors.

Comment: Thank's for your reply! Have to admit this did concern me as it's low resolution image seemed misleading but that's just me being picky.

I'm doing a full hard drive wipe now to reinstall Windows 8.1 see what happens before the main drivers are installed onto the system. Funny things did begin to happen after nvidia's 347.88 driver for Window 8.1, GTX 660 came out but i guess we'll see soon enough!

Thank you for your response :)